# Download blob using url of the blob and sas token in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-blob-storage

I am very new to java script. I want to download a blob file from the azure blob storage. I have the sas token and complete url to the individual block blob
The url looks like this:
https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/ABC/ABC/20216063/cvf.gbl

In online i have come across download methods which require container name and blob name. I dont know the container name and blob name. i have the url to the individual blob file.

How to download the blob using only sas token and the blob url using java script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an HTTP GET request and pipe its response into a writable file stream. With the below code you could download the file if you don't the blob name.

```
    const sasurl="your sas url";
    const https = require('https');
    const url = require('url');;
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const filename=url.parse(sasurl).pathname.split('/').pop();
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    const request = https.get(sasurl, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    });
```

Comment: The response is not sending the file to the client? Can you tell me what I doing wrong? Is it a problem-related to `http` and `https`?